# Trying to create an Auto-Clear Script for a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a Lunch Order sheet for the school that I work at. I'm having some issues with figuring out the logistics of creating an "Auto-Clear" script for a range of cells on every sheet (27 Separate sheets) within a spreadsheet.

Could someone help me with the AppsScript?

So far I've tried checking out other questions like this but I don't know how to use AppsScript to properly pull sheets data.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may want to consider using a [form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) to collect lunch orders instead of having everyone fill in a spreadsheet.

Comment: This site is for clearly defined programming questions so it is probably not the best forum for you. See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/13045193)

Answer (score 0):

#### Clear ranges on many sheets

```
function lunchclear() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cA = [{name:"Sheet0",range:"A1:Z10"},{name:"Sheet1",range:"A2:Z22"}];//add more objects on your own
  cA.forEach(obj => {
    ss.getSheetByName(obj.name).getRange(obj.range).clearContent()
  });
}
```